# OrientDB Javascript Server Side Functions

Tags: javascript, function, server, documentation, orientdb

I want to implement the whole server logic of the OrientDB with the server side Javascript functions but I can´t find a documentation of the server side JS implemantation. The best tutorial that I found is this one:

http://pizzaconnections.net/2015/04/02/orientdb-functions-by-samples-1/

But thats not enough, for example I want to know, how I can traverse to the graph with JS or if I have a vertex saved in a JS variable how to see which edges are going out from this vertex?

Can someone give me few links with good tutorials or maybe a good documentation for Javascript server side functions?

Comment: Hi @Jonny Right, would you like two examples (also only with the `command` OrientDB function) related to your requests ?

Comment: Hi LucaS, thanks for responding. Michela Bonizzi´s examples solved my problems. More examples are not necessary atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the examples that I made in according with your request:

I have this schema:

[image]

JS function to traverse the graph:

[image]

and the output(just a piece):

[image]

JS function to see which edges are going out from a specific vertex:

[image]

and the output:

[image]

Hope it helps,

Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me alot. Exactly where I was looking for.